# Should it be possible to pause a question that is "under investigation" by OP?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I see valid questions where a comment or answer has partially helped the original poster, but now he's doing some more investigation and "will update the question later".

I don't think this should be closed because it's a valid question, but at the same time, it sucks when you want to answer questions and you keep seeing these types of questions where you can't really help until OP provides new information.

Would it be helpful to allow people to **pause** a question? This would keep the question open, but with a flash indicating that the OP is doing some investigation and will either provide more info later or close the question if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure you can pause a question. That is what closing **does**. The question in put *on hold* when closed, automatically morphing into *closed* when not reopened after a while.

Just vote or flag to close. The question can always be reopened once the OP comes back and adds the additional information. That way, if the OP does *not* come back, the question won't continue cluttering up the site either.

Adding a new pausing state on top of that doesn't achieve anything.